# An ArrayList that should have objects from a created class but print as null

Tags: java, arraylist

My first class that creates the ArrayList and populates it with the Skill objects

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Skill {
    String skillName;
    int skillValue;
    public static ArrayList<Skill> skillList = new ArrayList<Skill>();

    public Skill(String newSkillName, int newSkillValue){
        setSkillName(newSkillName);
        setSkillValue(newSkillValue);
    }

    public static void initializeSkillList(){
        //Creating the Skill obj's
        Skill str = new Skill("Str", 1);
        Skill dex = new Skill("Dex", 1);
        Skill intl = new Skill("Int", 1);
        Skill con = new Skill("Con", 3);

        //Adding them to the Skill ArrayList
        skillList.add(str);
        skillList.add(dex);
        skillList.add(intl);
        skillList.add(con);

        //Debug statement to check if the values are correct
        System.out.println(skillList.get(1).skillValue);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to access the objects skillValue and skillName from the ArrayList in my Main.java class. I have setters and getters.
This is the Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Character playerCharacter;
    static boolean charCreationComplete = false;
    static boolean endGame = false;
    static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("\n\nWelcome to Garterra!\n\n");
        Archetype.initializeArchetypeList();
        Skill.initializeSkillList();

        if (!charCreationComplete){
            charCreation(scnr);
            charCreationComplete = true;
        }
```

`charCreation(scnr);` then accesses the skillList through getters and setters

charCreation() Method:

```
private static void charCreation(Scanner scnr){

    System.out.println("\nEnter player name:\n\n");
    String newName = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You Entered " + newName + " for your name!\n");
    System.out.println("Next, Choose your Archetype: 0 = Ranger\n");
    int archetypeIndex = scnr.nextInt();
    Character.currArchetype = Archetype.archetypeList.get(archetypeIndex);
    Character.archetypeName = Archetype.archetypeList.get(archetypeIndex).getArchetypeName();
    System.out.println("You have chosen " + Character.archetypeName + ".\nThis gives you " + Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints + " total spendable skill points!\n");
    System.out.println("Now, spend those skill points.\n");
    if (Character.currArchetype.getArchetypeName().contains("Ranger")){
        Ranger.dexModifierCalc(1);
        Ranger.conModifierCalc(1);
    }
    while (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints > 0){
        System.out.println("How many points would you like to put into Strength?\nThis impacts your melee weapon damage and carry weight.\n");
        int strAddPoints = scnr.nextInt();
        Skill.skillList.get(0).setSkillValue(Skill.skillList.get(0).getSkillValue() + strAddPoints);
        Character.currArchetype.setTotalSpendableSkillPoints(Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints - strAddPoints);
        strAddPoints = 0;
        System.out.println("You now have " + Skill.skillList.get(0).getSkillValue() + "\n");
        if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints == 0){
            break;
        }
        if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints > 0){
            System.out.println("How many points would you like to put into Dexterity?\nThis impacts your ranged weapon damage.\n");
            int dexAddPoints = scnr.nextInt();
            Skill.skillList.get(1).setSkillValue(Skill.skillList.get(1).getSkillValue() + dexAddPoints);
            Character.currArchetype.setTotalSpendableSkillPoints(Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints - dexAddPoints);
            dexAddPoints = 0;
            System.out.println("You now have " + Skill.skillList.get(1).getSkillValue() + "\n");
        }
            if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints == 0){
            break;
        }
        if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints > 0){
            System.out.println("How many points would you like to put into Intelligence?\nThis impacts your magic damage.\n");
            int intAddPoints = scnr.nextInt();
            Skill.skillList.get(2).setSkillValue(Skill.skillList.get(2).getSkillValue() + intAddPoints);
            Character.currArchetype.setTotalSpendableSkillPoints(Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints - intAddPoints);
            intAddPoints = 0;
            System.out.println("You now have " + Skill.skillList.get(2).getSkillValue() + "\n");
        }
            if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints == 0){
            break;
        }
        if (Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints > 0){
            System.out.println("How many points would you like to put into Strength?\nThis impacts your melee weapon damage and carry weight.\n");
            int conAddPoints = scnr.nextInt();
            Skill.skillList.get(3).setSkillValue(Skill.skillList.get(3).getSkillValue() + conAddPoints);
            Character.currArchetype.setTotalSpendableSkillPoints(Character.currArchetype.totalSpendableSkillPoints - conAddPoints);
            conAddPoints = 0;
            System.out.println("You now have " + Skill.skillList.get(3).getSkillValue() + "\n");
        }
    }
    int newHealthPoints = Character.healthPointsCalc();
    System.out.println("You have " + newHealthPoints + " health points!\n\n");
    int newTotalCarryWeight = Character.carryWeightCalc(Character.currArchetype.getLevel());
    System.out.println("Your total carry weight is " + newTotalCarryWeight + ".\n");
    int newExperince = 0;
    playerCharacter = new Character(newName, newHealthPoints, newExperince, 1, Archetype.archetypeList.get(archetypeIndex), newTotalCarryWeight);
}
```

Comment: You first need to create an object inside main(), and then call initializeSkillList() on that object

Comment: Please include the definition of `charCreation`

Comment: Why create those object inside of the class, why not create them in main and then name each type of skill when creating a new Skill using its constructor. Making a list "skillList " inside the clas "Skill" breaks the whole concept of OOP. It is maybe better to have another class playerSkills and then have a list of Skill there, it would make much more sense

Comment: I initially had the initializeSkillList() method and "skillList" list in a different Character class but it wouldn't work so I tried moving it but that didn't fix it but even the print statement in the method doesn't print the correct values it only gives null or 0

Comment: _What_ is printed as null, which line?

Comment: The debug statement inside of the initializeSkillList() method that is meant to print the skillValue but it prints 0 and when I ask for the skillName it gives null but I checked and the list is the correct size its like it's filled with empty Skill objects

Answer (score 0):

If you create a getter for "skillList" then you can just say

```
Skill.getSkillList();
```

And then do whatever you want with this list.
To make your code a little better, change this

```
public static ArrayList<Skill> skillList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to this

```
public static List<Skill> skillList = new ArrayList<>();
```